# Shouldn't solar cells be nonreflective?

Tags: energy, efficient-energy-use, solar-cells

If solar cells take energy from light, then why do they reflect it? How come they can take energy without actually affecting the source?

Shouldn't reflected light (as a minimum) have a lower frequency?

Assume that there exist a "perfect solar cell" (i.e. one that takes 100% energy from light). Shouldn't it be nonreflective?

Comment: is the reflection of a solar cell as good as the reflection in your bathroom mirror?  No, it's much darker, right?   Because the solar cell DOES absorb energy, the glass has a special coating to maximise this.

Comment: The glass of a solar cell is actually tweaked to reduce the reflectivity and allow more light to reach the cell.

Comment: Started typing in the wrong place...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good question!

Solar cells made of silicon are naturally quite reflective (30%), and there is quite an art to making them less so - because any sunlight reflected is not available for power conversion. Antireflective coatings are not easy to make since they tend to work best at one wavelength and angle of incidence; you try to make them so the total power extracted from the sun will be greatest, but that may mean some wavelengths will be reflected. Note also that the reflected photons typically didn't make it into the silicon - in other words, the solar cell didn't extract some energy and reject a lower energy photon.

At [this website](http://www.pveducation.org/pvcdrom/design/anti-reflection-coatings) you can see a more detailed description - I will just reproduce here the plot of reflectivity for "no coating", "under glass", and "optimized" coating. As you can see, a lot is done to mitigate the problem, but as mmesser314 pointed out, even things that are almost "perfectly" (99%) black will reflect 1% of the light, which is quite enough for the eye to pick up.

[image]

Comment: This shows the result for a single layer antireflection coating. This is the most common because it is cheaper and good enough for most purposes. For completeness, you can reduce reflection with multiple layers.

Comment: @mmesser314 - indeed; that (multi-layer coating) is almost always done for high quality optics. For solar panels, the additional efficiency gains from more coatings quickly isn't worth the extra cost...

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to make anything be truly black. At any frequency, some light will be absorbed, some reflected, and some transmitted.

Eye response to light is logarithmic - We can see bright light, but also much dimmer light. So if 99% of the light is absorbed, that still may not appear black.

Smooth surfaces produce a mirror like reflection. If illuminated by the Sun, all the photons arrive from more or less the same direction. They have the same direction after reflection. If you eye is in the path of the reflected light, it receives all the reflected light. This is much brighter than a diffuse reflection from a rough surface, where light is scattered in all directions, and you only receive a small fraction of the total.

Typically, reflection does not change the photons. It just reduces the number of them. If the reflected light is redder, it is because bluer photons were absorbed.

Answer (score 0):

How come they can take energy without actually affecting the source?
Well the source is the sun, so it just sends out light and it doesn't matter where it goes, the sun will keep out sending out light, so it will be sunny tomorrow, amd the next day and the next day.....it will keep on going for a long time

Shouldn't reflected light (as a minimum) have a lower frequency?

It does. The light from the sun is actually a range of frequenies and the solar uses some of these frequencies to make electrical energy.   So the light coming in to the solar cell gives up some of its energy into the cell and the light reflected from the cell is at a lower frequency because it has lost energy.

Assume that there exist a "perfect solar cell" (i.e. one that takes 100% energy from light). Shouldn't it be nonreflective?

Sure, we would love to make a solar cell that good but we can't and yes it would be non reflective because all the solar energy going in would stay inside the cell, none comes back out so no reflection.

Comment: Light is not always redder when energy is absorbed. Think of green plants. Chlorophyll absorbs red and blue, converting it to chemical energy. Green is reflected.